# Can an external Blu-Ray device be used with a Mac?

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, blu-ray

You can't buy a mac with a blu-ray device in it, but there are external USB blu-ray recorders and readers available.

Is it possible to use (Backup files to BD-R discs and watch blu-ray movies) an external Blu-Ray recorder  on a Mac?

If it is not possible in OS X natively, is it possible from a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you can:
http://www.lacie.com/us/products/product.htm?pid=11218

its bundled with Toast software for reading/writing Blue-Rays on Mac OS X:
http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/default.html

--

dp